# Getting username while cron job is invoked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

As root, I can add user specific cron job by `crontab -u user1 -e` . There I can mention a shell script say `runbackup.sh` to get executed.

Since `runbackup.sh` script is used for many users, the script need to know the username (here `user1`) to do some user specific actions.

How the runbackup.sh could get the username when cron job invokes it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use "whoami" in your script runbackup.sh will shows who is excuting the shell.

Every user's cron job will start a shell process. So Every whoami show the running users' name.

Pls note that: All Users have permition to files mentioned in  runbackup.sh.